# How to sort and get latest directory by version number

Tags: powershell

In my folder (Test) I have multiple builds (Test_6.6.80.x).
I want to get the latest build.

This

```
$Directory = 'C:\Test'
$Latest = (Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory).Name | Sort-Object { [version] } | Select-Object -Last 1
```

Returns `TEST_6.6.80.12` because the sorting looks like this

```
TEST_6.6.80.16
TEST_6.6.80.15
TEST_6.6.80.6
TEST_6.6.80.5
TEST_6.6.80.14
TEST_6.6.80.11
TEST_6.6.80.10
TEST_6.6.80.13
TEST_6.6.80.12
```

How do I fix the sorting?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$last = Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory | Select-Object Name, @{l='Version';e={[System.Version]::Parse($_.Name.Split('_')[1])}} | Sort-Object Version | Select-Object -Last 1
$last.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:!

```
$root='C:\Test'

Get-ChildItem $root -Directory -filter "TEST_*.*.*.*" | %{
    $version=[System.Version]::Parse(($_ -split '_')[1])
    Add-Member -InputObject  $_ -NotePropertyName  "Version" -NotePropertyValue  $version -PassThru 
    } | sort Version -Descending | select FullName, Version -First 1
```